# What is jQuery (edge) in jsfiddle.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, jsfiddle

In jsfiddle.net if one choose framework as jQuery or Mootools they will get an option for choosing jQuery ( edge ) and Mootools( edge ).

I googled it quite a bit but did not get any good answers. My questions are

1. What are those versions?
2. How are they useful to the fiddle creator?

Comment: And how come the older versions are no longer available in the dropdown!?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is the jQuery nightly build from github...

jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6.3pre Live From Git (b22c9046529852c7ce567df13397849e11e2b9cc)

Here is the link: [link](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js) (jsfiddle uses this)

Here is the jQuery github link: [github-link](https://github.com/jquery)

Answer (score 11):

An edge build usually refers to some kind of "nightly" or not yet released build. The cutting edge, basically the latest source packaged up.

Comment: cutting edge, living on the edge, beyond the edge, etc, etc.

Comment: @Anurag: i thought edge had some, you know what, ninja art in it.

Comment: @naveen - edge always has ninja art in it :)