# jQuery: Select data attributes that aren't empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to select all elements that have a `data-go-to` attribute that is not empty.

I've tried `$('[data-go-to!=""]')` but oddly enough it seems to be selecting every single element on the page if I do that.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

try

```
$(':not([data-go-to=""])')
```

UPDATE:

For the sake of not leading anyone astray, this answer will work in older versions of jQuery but is not future-proof.  Since @gmo and @siva's answers both seem to be working with later versions I defer to (and encourage you to upvote) their answers....and of course hope you have a fantastic day.

Comment: thanks, this worked great! I wanted to select only image elements, so I added $(':not(img[data-go-to==""]')

Comment: Does this not select all elements that don't have a blank 'data-to-go' attribute?  When the asker wants all elements with that attribute that are not blank?  (as Siva Charan's answer resolves)

Comment: don't really need any double quotes either... as in `$('element:not([attribute=])'); // gets all of <element attribute="">` or `$(':not([attribute=])'); // gets all of <* attribute="">`

Comment: This gets every element for me, including the one that has the data-attribute I'm looking for

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Safari but `$('[data-go-to!=""]:[data-go-to]')` does.

Comment: Can't make this working with jquery 1.10 (it founds 100+ results where I want only one) but gmo answer below is working ( `$("[data-go-to!=''][data-go-to]")` )

Comment: why not future proof?

Answer (score 212):

Just as further reference, and an ***up-to-date*** <sup>*<s>(may'14)</s> <s>(aug'15)</s> <s>(sep'16)</s> <s>(apr'17)</s> <s>(mar'18)</s> <s>(mar'19)</s>  <s>(may'20)</s> (**jan'22**)*</sup>...
Answer that works with:

> ###Empty strings:
> If the *`attr`* ***must*** exist & ***could*** have any value *<sup>(or none at all)</sup>*

```
    jQuery("[href]");
```

> ###Missing attributes:
> If *`attr`* ***could*** exist & if exist, ***must*** have some value

```
    jQuery("[href!='']");
```

> ###Or both:
> If *`attr`* ***must*** exist & ***has to have*** some value...

```
    jQuery("[href!=''][href]");
```

---

<sup>***PS**: more combinations are possible...*</sup>

---

###Check this test in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for examples:

- `jQuery v1.9.1         ->` [<kbd>***jsFiddle online test***</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/SPb84/138/)
- `jQuery v1.11.0        ->` [<kbd>***jsFiddle online test***</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/SPb84/37/)
- `jQuery v2.1.0         ->` [<kbd>***jsFiddle online test***</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/SPb84/38/)
- `jQuery v2.1.3         ->` [<kbd>***jsFiddle online test***</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/SPb84/39/)
- `jQuery v2.2.4         ->` [<kbd>***jsFiddle online test***</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/SPb84/139/)
- `jQuery v3.2.1         ->` [<kbd>***jsFiddle online test***</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/SPb84/42/)
- `jQuery v3.3.1         ->` [<kbd>***jsFiddle online test***</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/SPb84/71/)
- `jQuery v3.4.1         ->` [<kbd>***jsFiddle online test***</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/SPb84/137/) <sup>*Last jQuery version available in jsFiddle at jan 10'22*</sup>
- `jQuery Edge           ->` [<kbd>***jsFiddle online test***</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/SPb84/43/) <sup>*[jQuery edge version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035328/what-is-jquery-edge-in-jsfiddle-net) (use with caution)*</sup>
- `jQuery v3.0.0-alpha1  ->` [<kbd>***jsFiddle online test***</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/SPb84/40/)
- `jQuery v3.1.1 Slim    ->` [<kbd>***jsFiddle online test***</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/SPb84/36/)
- `jQuery v3.2.1 Slim    ->` [<kbd>***jsFiddle online test***</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/SPb84/140/)
- `jQuery v3.3.1 Slim    ->` [<kbd>***jsFiddle online test***</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/SPb84/141/)
- `jQuery v3.4.1 Slim    ->` [<kbd>***jsFiddle online test***</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/SPb84/142/) <sup>*Last jQuery Slim version available in jsFiddle at jan 10'22*</sup>

---

###Or here in SO with this [Code Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).
<sup>** Snippet is running jQuery v2.1.1*</sup>

```js
jQuery('div.test_1 > a[href]').addClass('match');
jQuery('div.test_2 > a[href!=""]').addClass('match');
jQuery('div.test_3 > a[href!=""][href]').addClass('match');
```

```css
div,a {
    display: block;
    color: #333;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
h4 {
    margin: 0;
}
a {
    width: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.match {
    background-color: #16BB2A;
    position: relative;
}
a.match:after {
    content: 'Match!';
    position: absolute;
    left: 105%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test_1">
    <h4>Test 1: jQuery('a[href]')</h4>
    <a href="test">href: test</a>
    <a href="#">href: #</a>
    <a href="">href: empty</a>
    <a>href: not present</a>
</div>
<div class="test_2">
    <h4>Test 2: jQuery('a[href!=""]')</h4>
    <a href="test">href: test</a>
    <a href="#">href: #</a>
    <a href="">href: empty</a>
    <a>href: not present</a>
</div>
<div class="test_3">
    <h4>Test 3: jQuery('a[href!=""][href]')</h4>
    <a href="test">href: test</a>
    <a href="#">href: #</a>
    <a href="">href: empty</a>
    <a>href: not present</a>
</div>
```

Comment: this is it. Upvote this user right here. the other older answers are not working for me. I used the third example.

Comment: This is the one which is working. `$(':not([data-go-to=""])')` is not working anymore

Comment: Your solution is better and safer (last solution worked for me thank you very much)

Comment: jquery v2.2.0 '.check-box[data-field]:not([data-field=""])' works for me but not '.check-box[data-field][data-field!=""])'

Answer (score 20):

```
$('[data-go-to!=""]:[data-go-to]').each(function() {
    // Do Your Stuff
});​
```

Comment: This one works for empty strings and missing attributes, perfect

Comment: as of May'14 doesn't work, gives `Unrecognized Expression` error.

Answer (score 9):

Has 'data-attributename' and its value is not empty:

```
$('[data-attributename]:not([data-attributename=""])')
```

Has 'data-attributename' empty or not:

```
$('[data-attributename]')
```

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jelgab/yjJu7/3/)

Comment: This is the only answer that still works for me in June 2015.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about a simple selector, but you could use `filter()`:

```
$('[data-go-to]').filter(
    function(){
        return ($(this).attr('data-go-to').length > 0);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GGt3u/).

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) 
this should do it

`:not([attr="value"])`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/BfQT5/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

```
$('[data-go-to]:not([data-go-to=""])')
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/yupere/2/edit)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('[data-go-to]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('go-to')!="";
});
```

Using `:not`, `.not()`, `:empty` etc will only check if the element itself is empty, not the data attribute. For that you will have to filter based on the data attributes value.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/CmcJE/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
$('[attributename]').filter('[attributename!=""]')
```

Comment: These are two iterations though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('[data-go-to:not(:empty)]')
```

Comment: No go. `"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-go-to:not(:empty)]"`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

According to this, would be suppose to work, sad, that would have been a clean solution !

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$('.data .title td[data-field!=""]')
```