# Meteor Template Rendered in a package

Tags: jquery, meteor

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
  Template.hello.rendered = function() {
    $("#timepicker-default").timepicker();
  };
```

Inside of a package, independent of the actual template name.

Ignoring any other issues with the above pseudocode, what I'm wondering is how can I select DOM elements from within a package. Is it possible to write a package that can find the input element with data-attribute or a class of timepicker and generate the above code inserting the id of that element?

So you could write your markup like

```
<input id="mytimepicker" type="text" data-timepicker="default">
```

And the package would handle the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fastest solution is to use the [template-extension](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension) package. You'll get access to an `onRendered` hook which will fire every time any template in your app is rendered.

`$ meteor add aldeed:template-extension`

```js
Template.onRendered(function () {
  this.$('input[data-timepicker]').timepicker();
});
```

Place the above anywhere in your `client` directory and it should select all all inputs in the template being rendered where the `data-timepicker` attribute is set.

If you need to use this in a package, just add `api.use('aldeed:template-extension');` in your `package.js`.

Comment: I like this approach, but `this.$(':not([data-timepicker=""])').timepicker();` Seems to select all inputs that don't have the data-timepicker attribute set.

Comment: Try the updated answer. Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641258/jquery-select-data-attributes-that-arent-empty).

Comment: These solutions work in a simple fiddle but not here. It looks like the rendered callback is firing twice, not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: the data-attribute is not working out. For now I'm using the template-extension package and class='timepicker'.

Comment: unless there would be a valid reason not to use a class, I'll edit my question and approve this answer.