# Travel to outer component until reaching the one that has a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Example html code (Looks weird but my intention is to show that the outer components can be anything)

```
<div>
    <div/a/p/.. myAttribute="123">
        <p>
            <a>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery.ajax({url: "local.host?attribute= "});
                </script>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div/a/p/..>
</div>
```

What I want is that, from the inner script, before the ajax call is fired, I want to travel to outer parent components, till I can reach the component that has myAttribute. Then I will take the value of myAttribute and fill it into my url as `"local.host?attribute= 123"`

I found the closest of JQuery, but it requires to know the component type in advanced.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know how to get hold of the parent of the `<script>` element that's running, since you don't feature that in your question?  If you do, then `closest` should work with [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641258/jquery-select-data-attributes-that-arent-empty).

Comment: `jQuery.ajax({beforeSend: function() {};})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `'*[myAttribute]'` will do it fine.

```
$(el).parents('*[myAttribute]');
```

To target the current script. you can use

```
document.currentScript;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div/a/p/.. myAttribute="123">
        <p>
            <a>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                     var self = document.currentScript,
                         e = $(self).closest('*[myAttribute]'),
                         attrVal = (e.attr('myAttribute') );
                         console.log( attrVal );
                    // commented 
                    // jQuery.ajax({url: "local.host?attribute="+attrVal });
                </script>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div/a/p/..>
</div>
```