# Regex in javascript replace function

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dom

Am newbie to regex am trying to do some regex replace function in java script here is my content and code

```
jQuery("td[headers='name_head']").each(function (index, value) { 
var text = jQuery(this).html();
if( text.indexOf('<a href=') >= 0){
jQuery(this).text(text.replace(/<a href=.*\"$/, "")); 

}
});
```

Html content will be look like this

```
 <a href="/sf/tracker/do/editField/projects.srk_test_pro_ject/tracker.Activity?fieldid=fild20226" class="DisableItemLink" onclick="javascript:return ((adminTrackerForm.hasChanges.value == 'true' &amp;&amp; confirm('You have unsaved changes to your field ordering. If you proceed, your ordering changes will be lost. Continue?')) || adminTrackerForm.hasChanges.value == 'false');">Calculate Points</a>
```

i just want to remove only the value inside href ""

Please throw some light on this

Regards
Sathish

Comment: Can you post your try and result

Comment: Considering that your regex reads "`<a href=` followed by any number of characters, then `"` at the end of the string"... good luck getting that to work.

Comment: you can try the regex here https://regex101.com/ because I'm not quite sure what's the expected output

Comment: @ValentinCoudert expected output is just make the href value empty " "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method just retrieves the text contents which doesn't include any HTML tags. You can use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method with a callback function where you can get the old HTML content as the second argument to the callback and based on the old value generate updated HTML.

---

The better way is to update the `href` attribute value of `a` tag to empty by directly selecting them, there is no need to loop over them since all values need to be empty.

```
jQuery("td[headers='name_head'] a").attr('href', '');
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :** In case you want to iterate and do some operation based on condition then do something like this.

```
jQuery("td[headers='name_head'] a").each(function(){
  if(//your ondition){
    $(this).attr('href', '');
  }
});
```

or

```
jQuery("td[headers='name_head']").each(function(){
  if(//your ondition){
    $('a', this).attr('href', '');
  }
});
```

---

**UPDATE 2 :** If you want to remove the entire attribute then use [`removeAttr('href')`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method which removes the entire attribute itself.

```
jQuery("td[headers='name_head'] a").removeAttr('href');
```

Comment: i wrote the for loop since i dont want to change all the value i add the condition later in if condition

Comment: @sathishkumar :  in that case within callback do `$(this).find("a").attr('href', '');` or `$("a", this).attr('href', '');`

Comment: It worked Pranav thanks a lot one last question if you dont mind how about removing the whole href instead of just remove the href contents i wanna remove the href = "" completely

Comment: @sathishkumar : check the last update, use `removeAttr()` method

Answer (score 2):

Why would you reinvent the wheel?

You don't need regex to achieve this, you can simply do it this way:

```
jQuery("td[headers='name_head'] a").attr('href', '');
```

It will set `href` to `""` for all  `<a>` elements inside `td[headers='name_head']` so it will always respect your condition.

Comment: why am going for a foor loop is because i want remove href only for certain contion rest of href should remain

Comment: And this will just remove it only for certain `<a>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code; but something like this should help, don't think you need to use regex for this;

```
$('a.DisableItemLink[href!=''][href]').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    // do something with href
})
```

This piece of code selects all elements which have the class DisableItemLink with a location set and sets it to blank.

I am curious as to what you are trying to do in the larger scheme of things though, sounds like there might be better ways to go about it.

Reference: [some good selector combinations for links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641258/jquery-select-data-attributes-that-arent-empty)

Comment: Thanks for your response Nishan actually am trying to remove the whole attribute href for some text inside td just the href contents