# jQuery .each() not working, any other ways?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do a foreach with each in jquery.

My function jquery have a call for another function **showTauxPlafonds** so i want for every a i have a call for this function to return a result with ajax.

For every `<a>` I want when I click I have a call for my **function jquery** :

```js
$("a").each(function() {
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    showTauxPlafonds(urlTaux, $(this).attr('tauxPlafonds'));
  })
});


var showTauxPlafonds = function(url, tauxPlafonds) {
  if (tauxPlafonds != null)
    getAjaxedHtmlView(url, {
      tauxPlafonds: tauxPlafonds
    }, null, 'app_taux_plafonds_values');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="PSS" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Acceuil" style="cursor:pointer;width:350px">
Plafond sécurité sociale
</a>
<a class="mdc-list-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Taux et plafonds" style="cursor:pointer;width:350px">
Smic
</a>
```

Comment: You can bind directly to the anchor, no need for the each -  `$('a').on("click", function() {` although your code should work - what is your exact problem?  Is it that the links are loading a new page so it looks as if your code is not hit? Or that `$(this)` is not what it seems in `showTauxPlafonds(urlTaux, $(this).attr('tauxPlafonds'));`

Comment: I made you a proper snippet. Please add at least a dummy `getAjaxedHtmlView`

Comment: this line - `showTauxPlafonds(urlTaux, $(this).attr('tauxPlafonds'));` - where is `urlTaux` defined?

Comment: @Pete How i do that ?

Comment: How can you do what?  You haven't said what your problem is?

Comment: Have a read of [mcve].  You should be able to generate some example code *without* the ajax call (ie with a dummy function) to demonstrate exactly *where* your code problem is (hint: given the code provided, it's probably not the `.each`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean this, assuming url is the possible href of the link

There is no need for the `showTauxPlafonds` function since it is just testing the attribute which WILL be set unless you have `tauxPlafonds=""` in your code. Then you just test it in the selector:

```js
var urlTaux = "someurl";
$("a[tauxPlafonds!='']").on("click", function() {
  getAjaxedHtmlView(urlTaux, { 
    tauxPlafonds: $(this).attr("tauxPlafonds")
  }, null, 'app_taux_plafonds_values')
});
```

I do suggest however you do `data-tauxPlafonds="PSS"` to not create new type of attributes

See [jQuery: Select data attributes that aren't empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641258/jquery-select-data-attributes-that-arent-empty) for more example of testing an attribute

Comment: Another question where i put " urlTaux " like the code in the question  ?

Comment: I updated the answer - I cannot see where urlTaux comes from in your code

Comment: @mecab1995 my solution is more efficient

Comment: I have updated my code to ONLY select links that have non--empty tauxPlafonds attributes

Answer (score 0):

This method also solved my problem :

```js
$("a[tauxPlafonds]").on("click", function () {
showTauxPlafonds(urlTaux, $(this).attr('tauxPlafonds'));
});
```

Comment: Yes, but that is inefficient since all showTauxPlafonds does is test if the attr is empty which it is not since $("a[tauxPlafonds]") gets all As with the attribute